# why libusb-1.0 example not print any info on NetBSD7.0?

Tags: libusb, netbsd

Install libusb 1.0.19 on NetBSD7.0, use root user to run the sample "listdevs", 
can not print any info. ( which work well on centos7)

I can sure that there 2 usb mass storage devices.

Anyone try it?  Should other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

One uses `usbdevs` on NetBSD (since 1.4) to list USB devices.

Also, when one installs libusb-1.0.20 on NetBSD from pkgsrc (`devel/libusb1`), it does not install any `listdevs` program.